# Alternative to contextlib.nested with variable number of context managers

Tags: python, deprecated, with-statement, contextmanager

We have code that invokes a variable number of context managers depending on runtime parameters:

```
from contextlib import nested, contextmanager

@contextmanager
def my_context(arg):
    print("entering", arg)
    try:
        yield arg
    finally:
        print("exiting", arg)

def my_fn(items): 
    with nested(*(my_context(arg) for arg in items)) as managers:
        print("processing under", managers)

my_fn(range(3))
```

However, [`contextlib.nested` is deprecated since Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested):

```
DeprecationWarning: With-statements now directly support multiple context managers
```

The answers to [Multiple variables in Python 'with' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893333/multiple-variables-in-python-with-statement) indicate that `contextlib.nested` has some "confusing error prone quirks", but the suggested alternative of using the multiple-manager `with` statement won't work for a variable number of context managers (and also breaks backward compatibility).

Are there any alternatives to `contextlib.nested` that aren't deprecated and (preferably) don't have the same bugs?

Or should I continue to use `contextlib.nested` and ignore the warning? If so, should I plan for `contextlib.nested` to be removed at some time in the future?

Comment: You raise a good point about the arbitrary number of managers ... It seems to me like that point should be raised on a mailing list somewhere...

Comment: This is why Python 3 introduced [`contextlib.ExitStack`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack). See http://bugs.python.org/issue13585

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The new [Python 3 `contextlib.ExitStack` class](http://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) was added as a replacement for `contextlib.nested()` (see [issue 13585](http://bugs.python.org/issue13585)).

It is coded in such a way you can use it in Python 2 directly:

```
import sys
from collections import deque


class ExitStack(object):
    """Context manager for dynamic management of a stack of exit callbacks

    For example:

        with ExitStack() as stack:
            files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname)) for fname in filenames]
            # All opened files will automatically be closed at the end of
            # the with statement, even if attempts to open files later
            # in the list raise an exception

    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._exit_callbacks = deque()

    def pop_all(self):
        """Preserve the context stack by transferring it to a new instance"""
        new_stack = type(self)()
        new_stack._exit_callbacks = self._exit_callbacks
        self._exit_callbacks = deque()
        return new_stack

    def _push_cm_exit(self, cm, cm_exit):
        """Helper to correctly register callbacks to __exit__ methods"""
        def _exit_wrapper(*exc_details):
            return cm_exit(cm, *exc_details)
        _exit_wrapper.__self__ = cm
        self.push(_exit_wrapper)

    def push(self, exit):
        """Registers a callback with the standard __exit__ method signature

        Can suppress exceptions the same way __exit__ methods can.

        Also accepts any object with an __exit__ method (registering a call
        to the method instead of the object itself)
        """
        # We use an unbound method rather than a bound method to follow
        # the standard lookup behaviour for special methods
        _cb_type = type(exit)
        try:
            exit_method = _cb_type.__exit__
        except AttributeError:
            # Not a context manager, so assume its a callable
            self._exit_callbacks.append(exit)
        else:
            self._push_cm_exit(exit, exit_method)
        return exit # Allow use as a decorator

    def callback(self, callback, *args, **kwds):
        """Registers an arbitrary callback and arguments.

        Cannot suppress exceptions.
        """
        def _exit_wrapper(exc_type, exc, tb):
            callback(*args, **kwds)
        # We changed the signature, so using @wraps is not appropriate, but
        # setting __wrapped__ may still help with introspection
        _exit_wrapper.__wrapped__ = callback
        self.push(_exit_wrapper)
        return callback # Allow use as a decorator

    def enter_context(self, cm):
        """Enters the supplied context manager

        If successful, also pushes its __exit__ method as a callback and
        returns the result of the __enter__ method.
        """
        # We look up the special methods on the type to match the with statement
        _cm_type = type(cm)
        _exit = _cm_type.__exit__
        result = _cm_type.__enter__(cm)
        self._push_cm_exit(cm, _exit)
        return result

    def close(self):
        """Immediately unwind the context stack"""
        self.__exit__(None, None, None)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc_details):
        # We manipulate the exception state so it behaves as though
        # we were actually nesting multiple with statements
        frame_exc = sys.exc_info()[1]
        def _fix_exception_context(new_exc, old_exc):
            while 1:
                exc_context = new_exc.__context__
                if exc_context in (None, frame_exc):
                    break
                new_exc = exc_context
            new_exc.__context__ = old_exc

        # Callbacks are invoked in LIFO order to match the behaviour of
        # nested context managers
        suppressed_exc = False
        while self._exit_callbacks:
            cb = self._exit_callbacks.pop()
            try:
                if cb(*exc_details):
                    suppressed_exc = True
                    exc_details = (None, None, None)
            except:
                new_exc_details = sys.exc_info()
                # simulate the stack of exceptions by setting the context
                _fix_exception_context(new_exc_details[1], exc_details[1])
                if not self._exit_callbacks:
                    raise
                exc_details = new_exc_details
        return suppressed_exc
```

Use this as your context manager, then add *nested* context managers at will:

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
    managers = [stack.enter_context(my_context(arg)) for arg in items]
    print("processing under", managers)
```

For your example context manager, this prints:

```
>>> my_fn(range(3))
('entering', 0)
('entering', 1)
('entering', 2)
('processing under', [0, 1, 2])
('exiting', 2)
('exiting', 1)
('exiting', 0)
```

You can also install the [`contextlib2` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/contextlib2); it includes `ExitStack` as a backport.

Comment: This solution only works in a situation where the context managers to be used are 'entered' in the same context where they're assembled. In [this code](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/context_managers.py#L243), for example, the result of `nested` is returned for the caller to enter later. I don't see a way to implement this in Python 3.

Comment: You mean you want to construct a stacked CM in a function or similar, then *later* use that stack in a `with` statement? You can do that with an `ExitStack()` too; just create an instance in a variable, use `.enter_context()` to push context managers on it, then *later* use the instance in a `with` statement. You can pass the object around just like other Python objects.

Comment: If you want to postpone *entering* too, a subclass that takes a queue and calls `.enter_context()` on `__enter__()` (and handles exiting properly when an exception occurs) isn't too hard to write.

Comment: The one thing you need to be wary about is that *creating* the CM can raise an exception too; so passing in callables to that queue is probably the best approach, postponing creating the CMs until `__enter__` has been called.

Comment: Great suggestion. I was considering subclassing ExitStack to defer entering the contexts, but I wasn't sure if that was too hacky. Since you recommend it, I'm much more confident to try it. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs: the problem with `contextlib.nested()` is that you *have* to create your context managers first, before the call to `nested()`. Which means that in a list of `Foo(), Bar(), Baz()` if the *creation* of `Baz()` fails, `Foo()` and `Bar()` never have had `__enter__()` nor `__exit__()` called on them.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs: So a subclass of `ExitStack` should take callables that create the context manager, then call each in turn and ensure they are entered before creating the next context manager.

Comment: I wonder why they didn't add this to recent versions of Python 2.7 as well, since `nested` is already deprecated and the code for `ExitStack` is directly usable in Python 2.7. Do you think just copying this into my project is my best bet as long as I want to support Python 2.7?

Comment: I'd say so, yes. Import the `contextlib` version first, and if the import fails (`except ImportError:`) use this version instead. That way you'll use the stdlib version where available.

Comment: There's now contextlib2 if you want a backport to python2.

Comment: Note that there's `AsyncExitStack` starting in Python 3.7 in case you're using asyncio.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs wrap the entire thing in a context manager which does that, creating and filling the ExitStack on its own `__enter__`.

Answer (score 6):

It's a little vexing that the python3 maintainers chose to break backwards compatibility, since implementing `nested` in terms of `ExitStack` is pretty straightforward:

```
try:
    from contextlib import nested  # Python 2
except ImportError:
    from contextlib import ExitStack, contextmanager

    @contextmanager
    def nested(*contexts):
        """
        Reimplementation of nested in python 3.
        """
        with ExitStack() as stack:
            for ctx in contexts:
                stack.enter_context(ctx)
            yield contexts
```

Comment: This implementation has the same problem the original `nested` had. The context managers are already created by the time the `nested` function is called.  If the constructor for a context manager at index > 0 throws an exception, the preceding context managers won't ever be exited.

Comment: It does have that "problem", yes. That's _only_ a problem for contexts which grab resources when they're constructed (as `open` does, unfortunately). There are many contexts which do not function that way, and `nested` allowed you to return a single return value which can be used as a context for all the sub-contexts.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import contextlib

class nodeA(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print( '__init__ nodeA')

    def __enter__(self):
        print( '__enter__ nodeA')

    def __exit__(self, a, b, c):
        print( '__exit__ nodeA')

class nodeB(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print( '__init__ nodeB')

    def __enter__(self):
        print( '__enter__ nodeB')

    def __exit__(self, a, b, c):
        print( '__exit__ nodeB')

class nodeC(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print( '__init__ nodeC')

    def __enter__(self):
        print( '__enter__ nodeC')

    def __exit__(self, a, b, c):
        print( '__exit__ nodeC')

print( 'Start...')

a = nodeA()
b = nodeB()
c = nodeC()

print( 'Python version: %s' % (sys.version))

if sys.version.startswith('2'):
    print('Use python 2!')
    with contextlib.nested(a, b, c):
        print('hallo?')

if sys.version.startswith('3'):
    print('Use python 3!')
    with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
        [stack.enter_context(arg) for arg in [a,b,c]]

print('...end!')
```