# Python close an array of files in a safe manner

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have an array of files:

```
    part_files = [open(name, "w+") for name in part_names]
    ...
    [part.close() for part in part_files]
```

I would like to close them in a guaranteed manner even when there is an exception in between.

I am aware of two ways, namely `try catch finally` and `contextlib.nested` however I'd like to know which is preferred and would work on both 2.7 and 3.0. From what I understand `contextlib.nested` is deprecated in 3.0

Comment: `contextlib` is not deprecated, but `contextlib.nested()` *is*, as it won't handle exceptions when opening correctly.

Comment: Related: [Alternative to contextlib.nested with variable number of context managers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16083791)

Comment: Since you open them only for write, isn't it possible to write to the files one after another? I usually hate those questions but do you _really_ need to have them open all at the same time? Otherwise you could use `with open(name, "w+") as fileobj:` within a foreach loop over the names. Which would actually be the preferred way afaik.

Comment: If you use the try/finally approach, the trick is to use a `for` loop that has a try/except clause so that you continue after exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python3.3+, you could use [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack).
In Python2 (or older versions of Python3), you could use [contextlib2.ExitStack](http://contextlib2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#contextlib2.ExitStack), which is installable with

```
pip install contextlib2
```

---

```
try:
    import contextlib
    contextlib.ExitStack
except AttributeError:
    import contextlib2 as contextlib

partnames = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    # All opened files will automatically be closed at the end of
    # the with statement, even if attempts to open files later
    # in the list raise an exception
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(name, "w+")) for name in partnames]
    print(files)
```

Comment: what does the 3rd line do (counting from 1)?

Comment: `contextlib.ExitStack` tests for the existence of `ExitStack` as an attribute of the module `contextlib`. In Python3.3+ it will already exist. In Python 2 it won't, so an `AttributeError` will be raised. The `AttributeError` is caught and handled by the `except`-suite, which tries to import `contextlib2`.

Comment: we can say `from contextlib import ExitStack` to replace lines 2, 3 I guess?

Comment: Yes, you could do that, but then be sure to change `except AttributeError` to `except ImportError`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
part_files = []
try:
  for name in part_names:
    part_files.append(open(name, "w+"))
  ... do stuff ...
finally:
  for part in part_files:
    part.close()
```

If an exception is thrown while opening files, it will still close all the files that have been opened so far

Comment: This will still not close some files if closing of the others fails.

Comment: @райтфолд doesn't close() not throw anything?