# Multiple with statements in Python 2.7 using a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, with-statement

## Question:

I am interested in doing a list comprehension **inside** a Python `with` statement, so that I can open multiple context managers at the same time with minimal syntax. I am looking for answers that work with **Python 2.7**.

Consider the following code example. I want to use the `with` statement on variables in an arbitrarily-long list **at the same time**, preferably in a syntactically-clean fashion.

```
def do_something(*args):
    contexts = {}
    with [open(arg) as contexts[str(i)] for i, arg in enumerate(args)]:
        do_another_thing(contexts)

do_something("file1.txt", "file2.txt")
```

Does anybody know if there is a way to involve a list comprehension inside of a `with` statement in **Python 2.7**?

---

## Answers to similar questions:

Here are some things I've already looked at, with an explanation of why they do not suit my purposes:

For **Python 2.6-**, I could use `contextlib.nested` to accomplish this a bit like:

```
def do_something(*args):
    contexts = {}
    with nested(*[open(arg) for arg in args]) as [contexts[str(i)] for i in range(len(args))]:
        do_another_thing(contexts)
```

However, this is deprecated in **Python 2.7+**, so I am assuming it is bad practice to use.

Instead, the new syntax was given on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893333/multiple-variables-in-python-with-statement), as well as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024925/python-create-a-with-block-on-several-context-managers/3024953#3024953):

```
with A() as a, B() as b, C() as c:
    doSomething(a,b,c)
```

However, I need to be able to deal with an arbitrary input list, as in the example I gave above. This is why I favour list comprehension.

For **Python 3.3+**, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3025119/2689923) described how this could be accomplished by using `ExitStack`. However, I am working in Python 2.7.

There is also [this solution](http://metapython.blogspot.com/2010/12/multiple-contests-in-with-statement-not.html), but I would prefer to not write my own class to accomplish this.

Is there any hope of combining a list comprehension and a `with` statement in Python 2.7?

**Update 1-3: Updated example to better emphasize the functionality I am looking for**

**Update 4: Found another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083791/alternative-to-contextlib-nested-with-variable-number-of-context-managers)**. This one has an answer which also suggests `ExitStack`, a function that is not available in 2.7.

Comment: This has all the feel of a "*I have `ship1 = 1; ship2 = 2` code and now I want an unlimited number of ships, how do I create ship variables with new numbers in code??? Is this even possable?*" nonsensical question. Loop over the with statement? `for item in list: with open(item) as f: f.read()` ...

Comment: I need to be able to have all of the context managers open at the same time though, i.e., `with open(item1) as f1: with open(item2) as f2: #do something with both`. I also have an arbitrary number of items.

Comment: Updated my example to show how the context managers need be open at the same time, not just in sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this yourself is really tricky, especially handling exceptions that occur while opening or closing the files. I'd recommend just getting a library like [`contextlib2`](https://contextlib2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that implements the `contextlib.ExitStack` functionality. Then you can do

```
with contextlib2.ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(arg)) for arg in args]
    ...
```

just like you were using `contextlib.ExitStack` from Python 3, and everything is handled correctly for you.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112 - this is definitely a good solution to my problem. However, I would like to use something inside Python 2.7 itself, without having to import external libraries. If such an answer does not exist, however, I will take yours!

Answer (score 2):

The major tasks of `with` statement is invoking the `__exit__` attribute of its context manager. Specially for dealing with files. So In this case due to this point and the fact that `open()` returns an `file_object` you can dimple use a list comprehension in order to create the list of your file objects and just call the `exit()/close()` manually. But be aware that in this case you have to handle the exceptions manually.

```
def print_files(*args):
    f_objs = [open(arg) for arg in args]
    # do what you want with f_objs
    # ...
    # at the end
    for obj in f_objs:
        f.close()
```

Note that if you only want to run some parallel operations on your file objects, I recommend this approach, other wise the best way is using a `with` statement inside a for loop, and opennning the files in each iteration (on names) like following:

```
for arg in args:
    with open(arg) as f:
         # Do something with f
```

For more safety you can use a custom `open` function in order to handle the exceptions too:

```
def my_open(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        file_obj = open(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as exp:
        # do something with exp and return a proper object
    else:
        return file_obj

def print_files(*args):
    f_objs = [my_open(arg) for arg in args]
    # do what you want with f_objs
    # ...
    # at the end
    for obj in f_objs:
        try:
            f.close()
        except Exception as exp:
            # handle the exception
```

Comment: This doesn't have the exception safety benefits of `with` or `ExitStack`, especially if opening one of the files fails.

Comment: @user2357112 Indeed, also exceptions during `exit()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kasramvd. Unfortunately, as @user2357112 pointed out, your example does not have the safety benefits of `with`, which is really what I am looking for. And yes, I am looking to do something in parallel with the objects.

Comment: @Miles  Yes that was a good point. In that case I think you must do them manually like the exit. Maybe using a decorator, or another function, check out the edit.

Comment: You're not closing the files if an exception occurs between opening and closing; you need a try-finally for that. Also, one of the major advantages of an `ExitStack` over manual handling is that it lets you cleanly propagate exceptions that occur in setup or teardown. With manual handling, it's quite awkward to propagate them instead of silencing them.

Comment: @user2357112 I've let the OP to takes care of that, because it can be a lot of scenarios based on main code which I'm not aware of them. And regarding the `ExitStack` I totally agree with that. It's more comprehensive and powerful for propagating the exceptions.