# __init__ vs __enter__ in context managers

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

As far as I understand, `__init__()` and `__enter__()` methods of the context manager are called exactly once each, one after another, leaving no chance for any other code to be executed in between. What is the purpose of separating them into two methods, and what should I put into each?

Edit: sorry, wasn't paying attention to the docs.

Edit 2: actually, the reason I got confused is because I was thinking of `@contextmanager` decorator. A context manager created using `@contextmananger` can only be used once (the generator will be exhausted after the first use), so often they are written with the constructor call inside `with` statement; and if that was the only way to use `with` statement, my question would have made sense. Of course, in reality, context managers are more general than what `@contextmanager` can create; in particular context managers can, in general, be reused. I hope I got it right this time?

Comment: You are confusing *creating* a context manager with *entering* a context. The two are distinct, and you can use the same context manager more than once.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

> As far as I understand, `__init__()` and `__enter__()` methods of the context manager are called exactly once each, one after another, leaving no chance for any other code to be executed in between.

And your understanding is incorrect.  `__init__` is called when the object is created, `__enter__` when it is entered with `with` statement, and these are 2 quite distinct things. Often it is so that the constructor is directly called in `with` initialization, with no intervening code, but this doesn't have to be the case.

Consider this example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__ called')
    def __enter__(self):
        print('__enter__ called')
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *a):
        print('__exit__ called')

myobj = Foo()

print('\nabout to enter with 1')
with myobj:
    print('in with 1')

print('\nabout to enter with 2')
with myobj:
    print('in with 2')
```

`myobj` can be initialized separately and entered in multiple `with` blocks:

Output:

```
__init__ called

about to enter with 1
__enter__ called
in with 1
__exit__ called

about to enter with 2
__enter__ called
in with 2
__exit__ called
```

Furthermore if `__init__` and `__enter__` weren't separated, it wouldn't be possible to even use the following:

```
def open_etc_file(name):
    return open(os.path.join('/etc', name))

with open_etc_file('passwd'):
    ...
```

since the initialization (within `open`) is clearly separate from `with` entry.

---

The managers created by [`contextlib.manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) are single-entrant, but they again can be constructed outside the `with` block. Take the example:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def tag(name):
    print("<%s>" % name)
    yield
    print("</%s>" % name)
```

you can use this as:

```
def heading(level=1):
    return tag('h{}'.format(level))

my_heading = heading()
print('Below be my heading')
with my_heading:
     print('Here be dragons')
```

output:

```
Below be my heading
<h1>
Here be dragons
</h1>
```

However, if you try to reuse `my_heading` (and, consequently, `tag`), you will get

```
RuntimeError: generator didn't yield
```

Comment: Oh man somehow all examples I remembered has the constructor call occur inside the `with` statement (e.g., `with Foo()...`). Now everything makes sense. Thx

Comment: Oh wait but then what about `@contextmanager`? Since it relies on a generator, doesn't it exhaust it on the first use, and thus make the repeated use of the object impossible?

Comment: So it's correct to say that only a subset of useful context managers can be produced with `@contextmanager` decorator; the rest require explicitly writing a class that complies with context manager API?

Comment: Please be carefull with the wordings. `__init__` is not really the constructor but the initiator in Python. `__new__` is the constructor.
You can see in the method signature of `__init__` that if "self" is passed as the first parameter the constructor has already been called or else you would not have an instance for "self".

Answer (score 18):

Antti Haapalas answer is perfectly fine. I just wanted to elaborate a bit on the usage of arguments (like `myClass(* args)`) since that was somewhat unclear to me (retrospective I ask myself why....)

Using arguments for initialising your class in a `with` statement is not different from using the class the usual way.
The calls will happen in the following order:

1. `__init__`  (allocation of the class)
2. `__enter__` (enter context)
3. `__exit__`  (leaving context)

Simple Example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, i):
        print('__init__ called: {}'.format(i))
        self.i = i
    def __enter__(self):
        print('__enter__ called')
        return self
    def do_something(self):
        print('do something with {}'.format(self.i))
    def __exit__(self, *a):
        print('__exit__ called')

with Foo(42) as bar:
    bar.do_something()
```

Output:

```
__init__ called: 42
__enter__ called
    do something with 42
__exit__ called
```

If you want to make sure that your calls can (almost) only be used in a context (e.g. to force the call to `__exit__`), see the stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865115/how-do-i-correctly-clean-up-a-python-object). In the comments you will also find a answer to the question how to use arguments even then.