# How to fix with statement deprecation warning

Tags: python, fabric

I have some Python code, using Fabric context managers, like:

```
with settings(warn_only=True), hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr', 'warnings'):
    do_stuff()
```

and every time I run this, Python gives me the DeprecationWarning:

```
With-statements now directly support multiple context managers
  with settings(warn_only=True), hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr', 'warnings'):
```

Why am I getting this warning and how do I fix it?

I'm a bit confused, because [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893333/multiple-variables-in-python-with-statement) implies I'm using nested managers, and that the fix is to rewrite them into the single line version that I'm already using.

I've tried re-writing it like:

```
with settings(warn_only=True) as a, hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr', 'warnings') as b:
    do_stuff()
```

and:

```
with settings(warn_only=True):
    with hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr', 'warnings'):
        do_stuff()
```

but both give me the same warning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that Fabric itself is using the deprecated `contextlib.nested`.

See https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1364

The only suggestion on the ticket seems to be to ignore it as they want to maintain backward compatibility with older versions of Python.

Answer (score 0):

The catch-all solution would be adding this at the top of your program:

```
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("ignore", DeprecationWarning)
```

Basically, this stops any DeprecationWarning from displaying.

Here's a couple links for understanding warnings. Hope this helped!

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/warnings.html

https://www.idiotinside.com/2016/12/17/python-warnings-framework/