# tensorflow how to use multiple cpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

how can I manually assign more than one device to one single op in TensorFlow (python API)?

For example, in order to assign one cpu to a graph, I would do:

```
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    # Define operation here
```

What if I want to assign cpu 0, 1, 2, 3 all to this same op?

It seems like I can't use a list of device names as the arg for tf.device. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: By default all cpus are used automatically and cpu:0 refers to all cpus on machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have [multiple `with` contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893333/multiple-variables-in-python-with-statement) like so:

```
with tf.device("/cpu:0") as cpu0, tf.device("/cpu:1") as cpu1:
    pass
```