# Using `and` instead of `,` when starting multiple context managers in `with` statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, with-statement, contextmanager

When writing unit tests, I was often using following pattern:

```py
with self.subTest("Invalid input") and self.assertRaises(ValueError):
  ...
```

But only today I learned that [according to python specs, I should be using `,`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) here:

```
with self.subTest("Invalid input"), self.assertRaises(ValueError):
  ...
```

And the specifications don't mention `and` as an option. Yet the tests always seemed to be working fine.

What are the possible problems when using `and` here? Why does it seem to usually work the same way as `,`?

Related: [Multiple variables in a 'with' statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/893333/7432927)

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an expression with the `and` operator. The `and` operator returns its first operand if it is *falsey*, or its second operand otherwise. Assuming `self.subTest(...)` returns something *truthy*, your code is equivalent to:

```
ctx = self.subTest("Invalid input") and self.assertRaises(ValueError)
with ctx: ...
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
self.subTest("Invalid input")
ctx = self.assertRaises(ValueError)
with ctx: ...
```

Or:

```
self.subTest("Invalid input")
with self.assertRaises(ValueError): ...
```

So, at best, what you have may be misleading. At worst it's a bug, since `subTest`'s context manager isn't being used.

If `self.subTest` returns a *falsey* value, then `self.assertRaises(...)` is never executed, which would be a clear bug in your test.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the excellent answer of @deceze, you can observe that yourself quite easily: you just need to create your own context manager.

Run the following code:

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
    def __enter__(self):
        print(f'Entering {self.id}')
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print(f'Exiting {self.id}')
        return self

with C(0), C(1): print('with statement 1')
print()
with C(2) and C(3): print('with statement 2')
```

You'll see that the following output is printed:

```
Entering 0
Entering 1
with statement 1
Exiting 1
Exiting 0

Entering 3
with statement 2
Exiting 3
```

What happens is that for the first `with` statement, both values are entered in order, then exited in reverse order (these are the semantics of Python's `with` statement). But in the second `with`, only the second item is processed (entered then exited) - because the first is thrown away by the `and` operator.