# Multiple variables in an 'async with' statement?

Tags: python, asynchronous

Is is possible to create **multiple variables** in an `async with` statement ?

I know that the equivalent synchronous version exists from here: [Multiple variables in a 'with' statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893333/multiple-variables-in-a-with-statement)

so the synchronous version looks like this:

```py
# some files
f1 = 'tests/test_csv.csv'
f2 = 'tests/some_file.txt'
f3 = ''


with open(f1) as a, open(f2) as b:
    contents_1 = a.readlines()
    contents_2 = b.readlines()

print('this is contents 1:')
print(contents_1)

print('this is contents 2:')
print(contents_2)
```

And this works nicely.

But will the same extend to the `async` version in a similar way ?

for example like this:

```py
async with A() as a, B() as b:
    while True:
        result_1 = await a.A()
        result_2 = await b.B()
        if (result_1):
            print(result_1)
        if (result_2):
            print(result_2)
```

would the above work or, if not, how could one make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's allowed. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-async-with-statement) says that the syntax of `async with` is the same as `with`, but with the keyword `async` before it.

The specification of `with` says that listing multiple items is equivalent to nesting them. So your code would be equivalent to:

```
async with A() as a
    async with B() as b:
        while True:
            result_1 = await a.A()
            result_2 = await b.B()
            if (result_1):
                print(result_1)
            if (result_2):
                print(result_2)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, i am just aware that `async` behaviour is specifically different from `sync` behaviour. So i am not just asking about **both** *syntactically* and also *behaviourally.*..

Comment: Behaviorally it acts just like nested single-variable statements.

Comment: If you want to know what `async with` does in general, that's a different question, since it has nothing to do with multiple variables.

Comment: Minor point: OP uses `a.A()` and `b.B()`, which is confusing since it implies `A()` and `B()` return objects that themselves have methods `A` and `B`.  Would be clearer if written as `a.method_1()` or similar.