# Create train and valid dataset in petastorm

Tags: python, tensorflow, petastorm

Versions : Python3.7.13, Tensorflow-2.9.1, Petastorm-0.12.1

In petastorm it seems as if only way to train model using dataset created from petastorm is to `fit` the model within `Reader` context manager like below as done in https://github.com/uber/petastorm/blob/master/examples/mnist/tf_example.py:

```
with make_batch_reader(train_s3_paths, schema_fields=cols+['target']) as tr_reader:
    dataset = make_petastorm_dataset(tr_reader).shuffle(10000).repeat(n_epochs).map(parse)
    history = model.fit(dataset)
```

I want to pass in train dataset as well as validation dataset how to do this?

```
with make_batch_reader(train_s3_paths, schema_fields=cols+['target']) as tr_reader:
    tr_dataset = make_petastorm_dataset(tr_reader).shuffle(10000).repeat(n_epochs).map(parse)
    with make_batch_reader(val_s3_paths, schema_fields=cols+['target']) as val_reader:
         val_dataset = make_petastorm_dataset(val_reader).shuffle(10000).repeat(n_epochs).map(parse)
         history = model.fit(tr_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset)
```

Is this efficient way to solve the issue I'm facing? Are there alternative ways such as using dataset outside of context manager or not use context manager at all?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about make_batch_reader but the "*with*" statement can take multiple statements. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893333/multiple-variables-in-a-with-statement) for more information.

In your case, this should work -

```
with make_batch_reader(train_s3_paths, schema_fields=cols+['target']) as tr_reader, make_batch_reader(val_s3_paths, schema_fields=cols+['target']) as val_reader:
    tr_dataset = make_petastorm_dataset(tr_reader).shuffle(10000).repeat(n_epochs).map(parse)
    val_dataset = make_petastorm_dataset(val_reader).shuffle(10000).repeat(n_epochs).map(parse)
    history = model.fit(tr_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset)
```