# Python with for list of things

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

If I have a list of things I want to use in a `with` block, how can I do that? If there are a fixed number of things, you can write them out like so:

```
with (
    items[0] as inner_0,
    items[1] as inner_1,
    ...
):
    ...
```

In my case, the number of things I need to `__enter__` is unknown, so I would like to have something like this:

```
with items as inners:
    # inners[n] is whatever items[n].__enter__() returned
```

The documentation of ["The `with` Statement"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) does not support this and I can't find any utilities to do this in [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html).

Comment: You missed `contextlib.ExitStack` which exists for precisely this purpose. [This answer on one of the duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50266687/364696) covers it in detail.